# How to mount an external encrypted drive?

Tags: debian, mount, disk-encryption

My computer stopped working so I'm plugging the hard drive with a USB adapter to another computer to recover my files.
After plugging it the passphrase prompt appears to unlock the volume, I type the passphrase and get this:
**"Unable to mount Encrypted Drive: The unlocked device does not have a recognizable file system on it."**

The passphrase is correct. The drive was encrypted using the Debian installation. The GRUB partition mounts ok.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the encrypted filesystem is toast. Hopefully not.

Depending on what sorts of encryption options you chose, you may need slightly different commands. But you can try this to start. If it doesn't just work, looking at *where* it fails may help you debug your problem better.

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 foo
# mount /dev/mapper/foo /mnt
```

You should be prompted to enter your password during the `cryptsetup` step. You'll obviously have to figure out what is `/dev/sdb5` on your own. I think you can use any name for `foo` to get it mounted, just use the same name in both steps. With any luck, `mount` will give you useful errors (check `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`, too). You *may* even be able to run `fsck` against `/dev/mapper/foo` if the encfs is corrupted, but I really don't know.

Comment: At $ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen
I get: "Cannot use device /dev/sdb5 which is in use (already mapped or mounted)."

Comment: Yes, sdb5 is right and probably its already mapped from a GUI attempt as you say. There's a "luks-..." on /dev/mapper, when mounting that it asks me for the passphrase and I get: "unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'". The device i want to mount is the Debian filesystem with my home directory and all. I don't know if this makes it more difficult to recognize the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me with this.

`$ umount /media/user/...`
manually unmount filesystem

`$ lvs`
information about logical volumes

`$ vgs`
information about volume groups

`$ vgchange -a y X`
change attributes of a volume group

`$ lvs`

`$ fsck.ext4 -y /dev/mapper/x-root`
"*filesystem checker*" check and optionally repair filesystems

`$ mount /dev/mapper/x-home /mnt`
manually mount filesystem

The moment the filesystem was mounted i copied all information on the external drive.